# disabled attribute doesn't work with required attribute on select tag

Tags: select, angular, required, angular2-forms, disabled-input

i have the following part of html template:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="medium-3 columns">
        <label>Category
        <select [(ngModel)]="item.cat" name="cat" required>
            <option *ngFor="let a of categories" [ngValue]="a">{{a.name}}</option>
        </select>
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="medium-3 columns">
        <label>Categoria
        <select [(ngModel)]="item.place" name="place" [disabled]="!item.cat">
            <option *ngFor="let c of places" [ngValue]="c">{{c.name}}</option>
        </select>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see the second `select` is disabled until the users choose one option from first select. So if the users choose an option from the first select, the second select become active.

Now i want to add `required` attribute even to the second select. But if i do it the second `select` is always disabled.

Isn't this behaviour weird?

Here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sx1qFH607cjmdTxPcvjl) (thanks to Stefan Svrkota).

Comment: Well, I just tried to re-create this problem, but your code works fine for me. Here's plnkr with expected behaviour of your code, check it out: http://plnkr.co/edit/QX3LfN

Comment: You might need to update to the latest Angular2 version.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I have already the latest version (RC6).

Comment: @StefanSvrkota Your code works but doesn't do what i need. You add `disabled` on `option` tag instead of `select`. I want that the items of the second `select` menu are nor selectable nor visible.

Comment: The mistery deepens: it works if there are positive conditions for Angular disabled tag. For example if i use [disabled]="firstSelect" instead of [disabled]="!firstSelect" it works with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

[disabled] works on a boolean expression if expression returns/evaluates to true it will be disabled otherwise not. In your case you have bind the disabled property with a number value. which is evaluating nothing